# How to play mkv video in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, video-streaming

I have a video file in MKV format, i want to play that file on mobile app.
This is my current code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo-av';

const VideoPlayerItem = (props) => {
  const video = React.useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video
        ref={video}
        style={styles.video}
        source={{
          uri: props.videoSource,
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode="contain"
        shouldPlay={true}
        isLooping
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
      />
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <Button
          title={status.isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
          onPress={() =>
            status.isPlaying ? video.current.pauseAsync() : video.current.playAsync()
          }
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default VideoPlayerItem
```

When I use .mp4 format file, I can play.

But, I can't play mkv format video.

who can help me about this issue?

Comment: Do you have the option to convert the video? I have also had issues playing non-MP4 videos

Comment: I was tried to convert this video from .mkv format to .mp4 format.
I can convert small size file with ffmpeg.
But, when I try big video file around 5 GByte, this stopping on converting.

if anyone know about this way solution, please help me, too